# Change in apparent magnification

Tags: webfonts, magnification

Firefox suddenly began to display the Wall Street Journal web page (www.wsj.com) in much smaller magnification.This behavior corresponds to some sort of recent  Windows 10 automatic update. Explorer and Chrome behavior were not affected.